# AudioKit 5.3.0 MIDICallbackInstrument Not Working

Tags: swift, audiokit

I'm trying to get a naive case working where Midi is read from a file and have the AppleSequencer relay event information to the console via print:

```swift
let path = "FullPath/To/MIDI_sample.mid"
let sequencer = AppleSequencer(fromURL:  URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
let callbackInstr = MIDICallbackInstrument()

func initializeSession() {
    sequencer.setGlobalMIDIOutput(callbackInstr.midiIn)
    callbackInstr.callback = myCallBack
    sequencer.enableLooping()
    
    sequencer.setTempo(85.0)
    sequencer.addTimeSignatureEvent(timeSignature: TimeSignature(topValue: 4, bottomValue: .four))
    sequencer.setLength(Duration(beats: 4.0))

    sequencer.play()
    print(sequencer.isPlaying)
    usleep(UInt32(5000000))
    print(sequencer.isPlaying)
}

func myCallBack(a: UInt8, b:MIDINoteNumber, c:MIDIVelocity) -> () {
    print(a,b,c);
}

initializeSession()
```

The console output right now is:

```
2022-01-07 11:33:36.507401-0600 audioKitCommandLine[84619:12905225] [seq]         SequenceTrack.cpp:927   Clear: Invalid beat range or track is empty
2022-01-07 11:33:36.507711-0600 audioKitCommandLine[84619:12905225] [seq]         SequenceTrack.cpp:1037  Merge: Invalid beat range
2022-01-07 11:33:36.507940-0600 audioKitCommandLine[84619:12905225] [midi] MIDI.swift:init():52:Initializing MIDI (MIDI.swift:init():52)
true
true
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I have seen elsewhere that `Clear: Invalid beat range or track is empty` is a warning, but I am expecting the `myCallBack` function to be called and produce output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to connect your callback instrument to the engine. Check out this bit from the Cookbook example: https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook/blob/c584a9a9aba5b64ce7ed5bc69dda05225e64c552/Cookbook/CookbookCommon/Sources/CookbookCommon/Recipes/CallbackInstrument.swift#L45-L46.